# Regex to extract Query String

Tags: regex, perl

I'm relatively new to regular expressions and could use some help. Can someone provide a regex (I'm using Perl) to extract a query string from a URL? I have tried the following but get an empty string:

```
my $string = 'http://www.google.com?queryArg1=1&queryArg2=2';
$string =~ s/^(.*)?//;
```

Ideally this example would provide the following string: queryArg1=1&queryArg2=2

More awesome if you could turn this into a hash:

```
my $hash = {queryArg1 => 1,
            queryArg2 => 2};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where does this string comes from ? Because HTTP servers knows about **QUERY_STRING** as is. Regex is maybe not the good solution.

Comment: @sputnick, Maybe he's parsing HTML and processing the urls therein?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use URI qw( );

my $uri = 'http://www.google.com?queryArg1=1&queryArg2=2';
$uri = URI->new($uri);

my $query = $uri->query();
say $query;

my %form = $uri->query_form();
say "$_: $form{$_}"
   for keys(%form);
```

Using a flat hash obviously can't handle repeated arguments, and loses parameter order. Loading [URI::QueryParam](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI::QueryParam) adds more methods to URI objects that you'd find useful if you need that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> More awesome if you could turn this into a hash

Its simple:

```
use CGI();
my $url = 'http://www.google.com?queryArg1=1&queryArg2=2';
my $hash = {};
if( $url =~ /\?(.*)$/ ) {
    my $cgi = CGI->new($1);
    $hash = $cgi->Vars;
}
```

No bicycles, just 1 simple regex and standard module CGI